# Failed to try function "permutations" in ghci (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am trying to walk through the functions in [`Data.List`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#2) of the Haskell stardard library and get an error when trying "permutations". What am I missing here? Thanks.

```
Prelude> map (\b-> b*b) [1,2,3]
[1,4,9]
Prelude> permutations "abc"

<interactive>:1:0: Not in scope: `permutations'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That library page you linked to is for the base libraries version 4 which come with GHC version 6.10.  Are you sure you are running GHC 6.10?  If you are running the previous version 6.8 then there will not be a permutations function in Data.List.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the pasted output that he hasn't loaded `Data.List`, so the version issue is probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

Data.List.permutations [was released in GHC 6.10.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.1/html/users_guide/release-6-10-1.html).  Chances are you have an earlier version.  But if you did have the correct version, you would have to load the `Data.List module` like this:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> permutations "abc"
["abc","bac","cba","bca","cab","acb"]
```